# Calculating angular momentum using the formula $\vec{v} = \vec\omega \times \vec{r}$

Tags: angular-momentum

I recently learned that $\vec{v} = \vec\omega \times  \vec{r}$.

$\vec\omega$ being the angular velocity vector of a particle, $\vec{r}$ being its position vector, and $\vec{v}$ being the linear velocity vector.

Let's suppose the particle is currently rotating around the Z axis.

We can always say: $\vec\omega = \vec\omega_o + \vec\omega_p$, where $\vec\omega_o$ is the component of $\vec\omega$ which is perpendicular to the $\vec{r}$, and $\vec\omega_p$ is the component which is parallel to $\vec{r}$.

Trying to use the above to calculate the particle's angular momentum, I run into a problem:

$\vec{v} = (\vec\omega_o + \vec\omega_p)\times\vec{r} = \vec\omega_o\times\vec{r} + \vec\omega_p\times\vec{r} = \vec\omega_o\times\vec{r}$

$\vec{L} = \vec{r}\times m\vec{v} = m\vec{r}\times\vec{v} = m(\vec{r}\times\vec\omega_o\times\vec{r}) = m(\vec{r}\times(\vec\omega_o\times\vec{r})) = m(\vec{r}\times(-\vec{r}\times\vec\omega_o)) = m((\vec{r}\times(-\vec{r}))\times\vec\omega_o) = m(\vec{0}\times\vec\omega_o) = \vec{0}$

This seems to disagree with the problem I'm working on from a textbook, where the angular momentum of the particle is not 0. Please help me realize my error in understanding.

Comment: Corss product is not associative.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thanks, you can add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you give an example of any case where the angular velocity has a component that is parallel to the position?